# Permission denied: '/Media' in Django Linux system

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, ubuntu

I'm using Django for my app development. In my setting.py file I've got following media setting

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = 'Media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_URL)
```

I want to save the file in my media folder for this I'm using

```
    excel_name_sheet = settings.MEDIA_URL+'upload_csv_file/'+ str(request.FILES['upload_bulk_data'])
    SaveCsvSheet.save_file(request, request.FILES['upload_bulk_data'], settings.MEDIA_URL  +'upload_csv_file')
```

I have took file using form which I got in request.FILES['upload_bulk_data']

I want to save the csv file in media folder , In windows I'm able to save the file in media but in Linux i've got [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Media'

I have tried to give permission using chmod but that didn't work
can you help me how can I fix this problem? it working in windows but not working in Linux

Comment: Try to give 775 permission `chmod 755 /Media`

Comment: Thank you , I have tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Save to `MEDIA_ROOT`, not to `MEDIA_URL`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure you are explicitly clear on your steps. What was the `chmod` command you issued and what was the output?

Comment: I have tried with Media_ROOT also still same problam